# Static height of an image within a flexible wrapper

Tags: html, css

I have a container with 3 boxes where the height and width of these is flexible. The first box takes up 60% of the containers width and 100% height. After 10% of a margin the second and the third box take up each 30% of the width and shall each use 45% of the height of the container.

This is done by the framework kube.css (https://imperavi.com/kube/) mostly. Within these boxes I have 1 image per box. And I want the images/boxes to align vertically perfect, where the layout is like that:
https://codepen.io/daiaiai/pen/qXRvOy

As background-image isn't a real option I have no clue how to do that with  proportionally correct scaling images.

I try it with that but that doesn't work out well:

```
.index_quicklinks div img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

I could solve it other way round by using the correct sizes for the templates of the images but I have no clue neither which the dimensions therefore should be.

Could somebody help me out with that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
.index_quicklinks {
   margin-top: 8vh;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```